# ¿Cuál podría ser la sintaxis correcta para insertar en sql un arreglo en un campo y un id para cada valor del arreglo?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli, sqlite

Tengo una tabla que se llama `TB_ProductCities` en la cual tengo que insertar dos campos, los cuales son `idProduct` y `idCity`, desde el frontend me envían dos variables una es un arreglo que contiene las múltiples cuidados seleccionadas por el usuario, básicamente la variable va a estar así para el campo idCity :

```
@ListaCiudadesSelecionadas varchar(500) = '1,3,4,66,62,101'
```

y en la otra  para el campo idProduct va a estar así:

```
@id varchar(500) = '1'
```

dejo una url de la imagen "https://ibb.co/kcDLK5t" ,como esta en esta imagen debería quedar

este es el código de como lo estoy intentando hacer

```
declare @ListaCities varchar(500) = '1,3,4,66,62,101'
declare id varchar(500) = '1,'



declare @ProgramacionIngresos2 table(IDError int)

    insert into [TB_ProductCities]
      ([idProduct]
      ,[idCity])
 

    select [value] as idProduct, [value] as idCity
    from string_split(@ListaCities ,','),@id)
```

Comment: Hay dos selects, imagino que debrías agregarle un union para unir las dos consultas no? Pero de todas formas retornan una sola columna que quieres insertar en dos.

Comment: Si quiero insertar las dos, pero no se la sintaxis correcta para definir el valor para cada una

Comment: ¿quieres insertar en idProduct y idCity el mismo valor?

Comment: ¿qué es lo que quieres conseguir? es decir, ¿qué registros pretendes ver al final en la tabla `TB_ProductCities`?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si quiero insertar un valor diferente para cada una de las columnas  es decir que al final la columna diProduct muestre 1,3,4,66,62,101 en cada campo y la columna idCity muestre lo mismo por cada campo

Comment: No sería entonces  algo así: `select [value], [value]  from string_split(@ListaPagosErrores2,',')`?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si muchas gracias, y en caso de que quiera ingresar una lista independiente para cada una sabes como seria ? es decir una lista para el primer valor y otra lista diferente el segundo campo ? algo así :
insert into [TB_ProductCities]
  ([idProduct]
  ,[idCity])
 

 select [value],[value] as idProduct
    from string_split(@ListaPagosErrores2,',')
    from string_split(@ListaPagosErrores3,',')

Comment: Brayan, entiendo que tienes un problema inicial, pero tu pregunta apuntó a lo que intentaste y te falló, vuelve un paso atrás y empieza por editar tu pregunta y explicar  que es lo que buscas y dando un poco más de información y contexto.  Te lo digo por que estamos caminando por un camino complejo y difícil y si explicas el verdadero problema tal vez te podamos ayudar con soluciones más simples y naturales.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho listo lo voy a tratar de explicar mejor

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no se si ya me entiendas un poco mejor ?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho el ejemplo que me mostrarte me funciona bien muchas gracias, pero me quedo la duda de que si necesito un arreglo independiente para cada uno de los  campos como seria? es decir descomponer un arreglo y insértarlo como lo estoy haciendo con  el campo idCity pero teniendo un arreglo diferente para idProduct, no se si me entiendas o te formulo otra pregunta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es insertar varias filas pero siempre del mismo `@id`, lo cual podrías resolverlo de esta forma:

```
insert into [TB_ProductCities] ([idProduct], [idCity])
select @id, 
       [value]
       from string_split(@ListaPagosErrores2,',')
```

Comment: muchas gracias maestro

Comment: @BrayanRomero por favor hace el [tour] asi sabes como funciona el sitio. No dejes un mensajes que diga gracias. Si la respuesta te sirvio, aceptala. si ayudo, tambien podes votarla positivamente...